# arcpy.AsShape function returning RecordSet not Geometry

Tags: python, arcpy, json

I have the following code:

```
feature_geometry = arcpy.AsShape(json_string, esri_json=True)
print feature_geometry
print type(feature_geometry)
>>><geoprocessing record set object object at 0x0E1D9F20>
>>><class 'arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjects.RecordSet'>
```

It's returning a record set however the [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000004m000000) says it should return a geometry object... What I am missing?

This is the ESRI_JSON object I'm passing:

```
{"displayFieldName":"","fieldAliases":{"OBJECTID":"OBJECTID","SHAPE_Length":"SHAPE_Length"},"geometryType":"esriGeometryPolyline","spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857},"fields":[{"name":"OBJECTID","type":"esriFieldTypeOID","alias":"OBJECTID"},{"name":"SHAPE_Length","type":"esriFieldTypeDouble","alias":"SHAPE_Length"}],"features":[{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":2,"SHAPE_Length":27314.085654472176},"geometry":{"paths":[[[-12374196.4669,7608025.6432999969],[-12373633.217700001,7580717.365699999]]]}}]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design, you are sending it a feature set and not a singular geometry.

If you'd like the Geometry on its own, do this:

```
import json
geom = arcpy.AsShape(json.loads(json_string)["features"][0]["geometry"], True)
```

We thought in many cases people would like to parse full Esri JSON feature sets and not just individual geometries, so that's why it works the way it does.